# Which is grammatically correct when using its or their

Tags: american-english, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I am writing a DoD IG evaluation report.  Throughout the report we refer to The Joint Task Force.  I am trying to determine which is correct to write.  The Joint Task Force follows their authorities or the Joint Task Force follows its authorities.

Answer (score 2):

You really should follow DoD protocol when using military terminology.  I also couldn't find any official style guide, but if you do a Google search for "Joint Task Force .mil" and check the results, it seems always to be singular:

> [JTFGMO Mission Statement](http://www.jtfgtmo.southcom.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/) *Joint Task Force Guantanamo **conducts** safe and human detention operations; etc.*
>
> [JTF-Bravo **partners** with Nicaragua to provide medical care in Waspam](http://www.jtfb.southcom.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/1487250/jtf-bravo-partners-with-nicaragua-to-provide-medical-care-in-waspam/)
>
> Based on Fort Bliss, Texas, [Joint Task Force North (JTF-N)](http://www.jtfn.northcom.mil/About-Us/) **is** a joint service command comprised of active-duty and reserve component soldiers, etc.